# Javascript class initialization and jQuery DOM in memory

Tags: javascript, performance, memory-leaks

Which is the best way between:

```
var myClass = function() {
    this.myContainer = function(){ return $(".container");}
    this.mySubContainer = function(){ return this.myContainer().find(".sub"); }
}
```

AND

```
var myClass = function() {
    this.myContainer = $(".container");
    this.mySubContainer = this.myContainer.find(".sub");
}
```

Is there any concrete differences?

The memory problem arose when I have seen that my web page, that has enough javascript  ( about 150KB of mine + libs ) takes more then 300-400MB of RAM. I'm trying to find out the problem and I don't know if this could be one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function myClass{
    this.myContainer = function(){ return $(".container");}
    this.mySubContainer = function(){ return this.myContainer().find(".sub"); }
}
```

Here you will need to call it something like `myClassInstance.myContainer()` and that means jquery will search for `.container` element(s) any time you are using that function. Plus, it will create 2 additional closures any time you will create new instance of your class. And that will take some additional memory.

```
function myClass{
    this.myContainer = $(".container");
    this.mySubContainer = this.myContainer.find(".sub");
}
```

Here you will have `myContainer` pointing to an object which already contains all links to DOM nodes. jQuery will not search DOM any time you use `myClassInstance.myContainer`

So, second approach is better if you do not want to slow down your app. But first approach could be usefull if your DOM is frequently modified. But I do not beleave you have it modified so frequently that you may need to use second approach.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a single variable you are trying to assign , then the second approach looks cleaner..

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are different.

**MODEL 1:**

In the first model, `myContainer` is a function variable.It does not contain the jQuery object.You cannot call any of jQuery's methods on the objet. To actually get the jQuery object you will have to say

`var obj = this.myContainer()` or `this.myContainer.call()`

**MODEL 2:**

The second model stores the actual jQuery object.

try alerting `this.myContainer` in both models, u will seee the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is different. after you fix your syntax error :

> function myClass(){... // the parentheses

**1st**

When you create a new object `var obj = new myClass()`, you are creating two functions, and the jquery object is not returned until you call it

```
var container = obj.myContainer();
```

**2nd**

As soon as the object is initialized the dom is accessed and you have your objects cached for later use;

```
var container = obj.myContainer;
```